# Parameterizing priors with related data-sets

Tags: bayesian, prior

I have a Bayesian model I'm using to compare two data-sets X_1 and X_2. I have a prior distribution I would like to use. This distribution could be parameterized by the mean and variance of some data-set X_p.

I know better than to use X_1 as the X_p needed to create X_1's prior, but I don't have a particularly clear proof that it would be wrong to use X_2 to parameterize X_1's prior and vice versa.

When creating priors for comparing two data-sets, is there a nice proof (or just a less-handwavy reason) that I cannot use the data-sets to parameterize the priors of each other?

I expect the right approach here is to simply randomly divide X_1 and X_2 into a testing and prior set, and use the segregated data to set their individual priors, however I'm very open to someone less stupid than me showing a better way forward.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare two data-sets X_1 and X_2"? And how do you use the Bayesian model in this task? Do you want to model the densities of both data sets and then compare those densities? And the prior for which parameters are you referring to?

Comment: I want to compare the unknown parameters that define the two distinct distributions X_1 and X_2 are drawn from? I'm sorry I don't understand how this is a question, the actual parameterization of the model doesn't matter in the context of this question.